# Dispatch redux toolkit async thunk by name/type

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-offline

need your help here.

I'm trying to use redux-toolkit with redux-offline. My issue is that I need to find a solution to call [asyncthunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) from redux-offline's "[effect](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/blob/develop/docs/recipes/customize-requests.md#effect)".

Ideally it should be :

```
dispatch({
 type: 'someOfflineAction',
 meta: {
   offline: {
     effect: { func: asyncThunkFunc, args: payload}
   }
 }
});

// from redux-offline custom config
const effect = ({ func, args}) => {
 return func(args)
}
```

But obviously not working because functions are not serializable

I searched a way to call asyncThunk by string name (and not by import), do you guys know if it's possible ?
Like :

```
dispatch({
 type: 'someOfflineAction',
 meta: {
   offline: {
     effect: { type: "asyncThunkName", payload}
   }
 }
});

// from redux-offline custom config
const effect = ({ type, payload}) => {
 return store.dispatch({ type, payload })
}
```

I'm using createSlice by the way.

Or maybe you have other solutions to suggest ?

Thanks and have a nice day.